# User Creation in External System

Tags: administration, user-management, user-record, external-app

Is there a way to automatically create a user in an external web application once the user is created in Salesforce?

What are the different ways to go about doing it?

If you have some examples that I can try out, it will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at SF [Integration Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm).

Comment: sure, thanks identigral! Is there any working examples that I can try in my developer editions? If so, kindly share them!

Answer (score 2):

So there are a couple of different ways of being notified when an sObject (in your case User) is created in Salesforce.

- [Platform Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm) This allows you to create a Custom Event type, and then create an Event via an Apex trigger, which your third party application can subscribe to to receive these events
- [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) This allows your third party applications to subscribe to create and update events on some standard and custom objects
- [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/pushtopic_events_intro.htm) This allows to create a PushTopic which your third party application can then subscribe to events when the condition of the PushTopic has been met
- [Outbound Message](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_managing_outbound_messages.htm&type=5) can be called from a Workflow which can send a SOAP API call to a third party application when the conditions of your workflow are met (I.e. a user gets created)

Comment: thanks Bryan! I will try out these and see how they work with my specific use case.

Comment: Hi @BryanAnderson, I was looking into Streaming API and wanted to let you know that user object is not supported under push topics. Reference URL: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/supported_soql.htm?search_text=objects

https://medium.com/@grace_62874/using-the-salesforce-streaming-api-5-pitfalls-to-avoid-b11b5e927214

Comment: I was able to create an Outbound Message and send the message to an external service (https://putsreq.com/) when the user got created. In case of third party application, will they be able to use this message to create user at their end?

Comment: @user3810861 yes it should give you the information on the User you should need

Comment: thanks, this helps!